# how to pass the id of the click CButtonColumn of CGridView going to the controller in Yii1.x?

Tags: yii

I have a custom CButtonColumn within the CGridView.
one of the custom buttons is firing a CJuiDialog. now the problem is,
how to pass the id when clicked, so that the Controller will get the id, then I can do pass a model and renderPartial it inside the CJuiDialog?

here's what i have so far

```
'see' => array(
     'label' => 'View',
     'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("mycontrollerName/view,array("id" => "$data->id"))',
     'click' => "function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $( '#view-dialog' ).data('id',$(this).attr('id'))
      .dialog( { title: 'View Details' } )
      .dialog( 'open' ); }"
),
```

having given that code snippet.. in the controller action, I want to have the id ..is it $_GET['id'] ?, or $_POST['id'] ?..it doesn't matter for as long as I can get it so that I can use it to query in the model function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few syntax errors in your code, but more importantly, you shouldn't wrap $data->id in any quotes.

```
'see' => array(
    'label' => 'View',
    'url'   => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("mycontrollerName/view", array("id" => $data->id))',
    'click' => "function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        $( '#view-dialog' ).data('id',$(this).attr('id'))
      .dialog( { title: 'View Details' } )
      .dialog( 'open' ); }",
),
```

So you are trying to pass the id value in the javascript code.
This is more of a jQuery issue rather than having much to do with Yii.

Run console.log($(this).attr('id')); you will probably see that you get an 'undefined' value. That is because the  tag generated by Yii for the button does not contain an id parameter.

The easiest solution is to use jQuery to work with the url parameter.

e.g.

```
$( '#view-dialog' ).data('id',$(this).attr('href'))
```

if the entire URL is not needed, you could use a regex to parse only the numerical ID.

Alternatively you will have to pass the id in the buttons option parameter.

e.g.

```
'see' => array(
    'label' => 'View',
    'url'   => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("mycontrollerName/view", array("id" => $data->id))',
    'options' => array('id' => $data->id),
    'click' => "function( e ){
    ...
```

However, please note that Yii will not render the value of $data->id in the 'option' parameter as this is not evaluated in CButtonColumn.
You will have to override Yii's CButtonColumn (see http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/372/cbuttoncolumn-use-special-variable-data-for-the-id-in-the-options-of-a-button/)

Personally, if I were you, I'd implement some Javascript in some external code and have a regex to parse the id from the URL.

Comment: am using CButtonColumns Buttons, and for some reasons I don't understand why $data->id is not being recognized. so the `$(this).attr('id')` doesn't work at all

Comment: ok, your question is starting to become more clear now. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I have tried that your modification. actually. I have tried a lot of variations before asking this in stackoverflow..I even found an article about the 'evaluateID' property of CButtonColumns. but unfortunately, it doesn't exist in yii 1.4

Comment: Yii 1.4? The latest version of version 1 is 1.1.17. Which modification of mine have you tried? My last snippet is incomplete and you would have to override CButtonColumn